# Stream STDOUT to file

Tags: stream, elixir

I'm trying to stream STDOUT/`:stdio` into a file using a `Task`. I've tried variations on piping and `Enum.each` as well as putting each function in the parent process and none of these solutions produce any errors at compilation. On the other hand none of them write to my file either. Here's my current best guess for how this should work:

```
defmodule OutputWriter do
  def start do
    Task.start(fn -> stream() end)
  end

  defp stream do
    Enum.each(IO.stream(:stdio, :line), fn line -> File.write(Path.join("test", "output.txt"), line) end)
  end
end
```

Comment: Try changing `write` to `write!`. Also, how are you running this? The VM will terminate if your main script reaches the end even if there's a Task running.

Comment: Changing `write` to `write!` didn't appear to have an effect. It's possible the process is being killed before it can finish writing. I'm starting it in a parent and then running a map reduce type work flow. There is a termination module that checks if all reduce processes have ended before killing the parent via `Process.exit` and `start_link`.

Comment: If `write!` doesn't raise that means there's no error in writing the line. If you can create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), I'll look into it.

Comment: I took a different approach and got my idea working. No streams for me :/